# run serverside method from jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I know the method that, from jQuery, using ajax I can invoke WebMethod from a aspx or asmx file. That's ok, but I only can place my project logic in ascx.cs files. It is a specific CMS and I can't do anything about it.

So my question is based on example described below:

Lets say users is logged in and is viewing an article. One user wants to mark it as a favourite, so clicks a button. On the server side without, refreshing the page, an appropriate method should run which adds this article to his favourites and then in client side there is an alert - 'Success'.

I dont want anyone to write the code for me for that it is just an example for desribing what functionality I would like to be able to achieve and which technology to use for that.

Thanks for the help.

P.S. I'm using ASP.Net 2.0

Comment: Can we asume that you have full access to the aspx files as well?

Comment: If I was you, I would try refactoring the code in aspx.cs into a method and then use a handler to call this method. or The other possible way is introducing Routing in ASP.Net which is surely not the best way of doing this but it should work.

Comment: I dont have access to aspx files. I can only write code in user control files. and then using CMS wmbed this controls on sites

Answer (score 1):

ASCX files are not directly accessible from the client (and as such, cannot be targeted via AJAX calls).

If your logic **really** has to be encapsulated in the ASCX file, you can add in an entrypoint `WebMethod` in your ASPX that calls the respective ASCX method instead. You'll probably encounter some difficulties related to the WebMethods being `static` though, so you may eventually need to refactor a bit, depending on how your code is structured now.

Answer (score 0):

You can make ajax call to remote page (with ascx control with your server side method) and then parse output (for example look for world "SUCCESS") to verify, that your method is executed. Not very elegant, but it will work.